# Is there an alternative for jcoverflip jquery widget?

Tags: jquery-plugins

The jcoverflip widget does not work with jQuery 1.9.1. I get an 'Cannot call method 'create' of undefined' error at this line:

```
var title = this.options.titles.create( el );
```

I have not been able to find an alternative. Anybody knows a widget which [does the same](http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo)?

Comment: my problem is identical, the plug-in looks good, but the error make it lame-like.